# How to decompile a regex?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to decompile a regular expression once compiled?

Comment: To what end?  Python is source based, so you should always have access to the original regex.  Even if you're trying to reverse engineer someone's .pyc files, it'd be easier to decompile the python object code to get the string, rather than decompile the regex.  The only possible use I could think of is trying to reverse engineer a pickled compiled regex...

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you want to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Compiled regular expression objects have a "pattern" attribute which gives the original text pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile('foo (?:bar)*')
>>> regex.pattern
'foo (?:bar)*'
```

Comment: Wow great, why can't I see it if I do a dir(regex) ?? I tried to introspect but cannot find where this property comes from...

Answer (score 8):

```
r = re.compile('some[pattern]');
print r.pattern
```