# Add boundaries around a regex without changing the regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, boundary

I'm trying to extract hashes out of a file, and want to add a boundary clause (`\b`) around the regex without changing the regex directly.

So for example, lets take this regex: `^\$1\$\w+\$\w+(.)?\w+..$` and I already have it compiled: `re.compile(r"^\$1\$\w+\$\w+(.)?\w+..$")`. Now I want to keep the regex as is and add boundaries around it without directly changing the regex itself. So something like:

```
def add_bound(regex_string):
    return r"\b{}\b".format(regex_string)
```

The only problem that I'm having with this is that my regex's are pre-compiled before the execution of them, so it turns them into something like `<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f846a189770>`. Is there a way I add boundaries around an already compiled regular expression?

Comment: Why do you need to wrap the `^\$1\$\w+\$\w+(.)?\w+..$` with word boundaries? It won't work then, because `\b^\$` will require a word  char before `$`. We only want to put word boundaries when we are sure the input is a literal word, having word chars at the start and end.

Comment: if you compile them to a variable, you can use `variablename.pattern` to get to the pattern. If that is really what you want to do. E.g. `regex = re.compile("[A-Z]")
regex.pattern
'[A-Z]'
`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you can do is de-compile it, add the boundaries, then recompile it.

```
import regex as re

def add_bound(regex_obj):
    new_regex_string = r'\b' + regex_obj.pattern + r'\b'
    new_regex_obj = re.compile(new_regex_string)
    return new_regex_obj


# example usage
some_text = """
ahello worlda
hello world
"""
regex_obj = re.compile(r"hello world")

print re.findall(add_bound(regex_obj),some_text)
```

The function above is for explanation/illustration, the one that should be used in code would be:

```
import regex as re
def add_bound(regex_obj):
    return re.compile(r'\b' + regex_obj.pattern + r'\b')
```

I used [How to decompile a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460686/how-to-decompile-a-regex) to develop this answer

I'm not sure why your example regex (`^\$1\$\w+\$\w+(.)?\w+..$`) starts and ends with anchors though (^ and $) since those would basically override adding boundaries (`\b`).